# Trying to remove flutter debug toolbar in vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

As the title says, I'm trying to remove this toolbar :

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

VS Code settings

```json
"debug.toolBarLocation": "hidden"
```

Editing process through the menu and the settings edit form.
File -> Prefernces -> Settings
Copy the text (without quotes) "debug.toolBarLocation" and paste it into the text input field where you see the prompt text "Search settings".

The subform of editing this parameter will appear.

> > Debug: Tool Bar Location
> > Controls the location of the debug toolbar. Either floating in all views, docked in the debug view, or hidden.

Select a value from the list.

More info: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: I thought it was a toolbar linked to flutter. That's why I never found the setting ^^'

Comment: This option affects all extensions. That is, this is a built-in vscode feature.

Comment: Can you please send out the steps? I tried open the Setting of VSCode, but I don't know where I can put the code.

Comment: @Raniys The answer has been changed.

Comment: You can also set `"debug.toolBarLocation": "docked"` if you want the toolbar to be stowed away in the Run menu.

Comment: @jeninja This is stated in the answer and in the documentation, at the link. Controls the location of the debug toolbar. Either `floating` in all views, `docked` in the debug view, or `hidden`

Comment: The **floating toolbar** is very annoying some times. Finally I can able to do something about this. the **docked** setting is great.

Answer (score 2):

You can also hide the toolbar within the VS Code GUI settings by changing "Debug: Tool Bar Location" to "Hidden"

[Click here to see what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gbV1.png)